# What is the first work featuring functional zombies at freezing temperatures?

Tags: history-of, zombie

I was reading 'Monster Hunter Alpha' (2011) by [Larry Correia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Correia) and there was a zombie that was able to function with temperatures well below freezing.  I am not including details as spoilers.  In this case the zombie was a hybrid, not your standard late night movie zombie.

I looked around and found [How do zombies survive the winter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/89653/13442) (*Walking Dead*) and the closed question [Would survival in a zombie apocalypse be easier in a colder climate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/29355/13442) but could not find anything else about active zombies below freezing, in any specific universe.

I suspect the hybrid nature in this novel was responsible for the activity, and I want to ask a different question about that, but first looking to see if there are any previous works by other authors with functional zombies at freezing temperatures.

All the zombies I have been exposed to fictional or historical have been warm weather undead.

What is the first work featuring functional zombies at freezing temperatures?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't do open-ended lists here, although you could legitimately ask about the first incident of such in fantasy or sci-fi literature, although I suspect Draugr might predate many cases, being zombies of Norse mythology.

Comment: @FuzzyBoot I intended to ask for first but on re-reading my question I see that I did not do that. Edited to be more clear.  I read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draugr and while it does not clearly state the function below freezing if they did not it would significant to be mentioned in that geographic area.  Your comment looks like an acceptable answer to my question.  If the question is re-opened please post it as an answer.